# 1-n relationship by location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, relation

I have a polygon layer and a point layer. According to the QGIS documentation, the childlayer has to have a foreign key. Unfortunately, my child layer has none. Is there a way to form the relation by geography only? So that even without having a proper foreign key, clicking on a polygon with the identify tool shows me all the points that are within this selected polygon in the attribute widget as child features?

I am aware I could create a new column in my child layer and assign that foreign key with the processing tools QGIS provides. As I have many layers to connect, this would be a rather time consuming process to do for all relations I want to establish!

Comment: Maybe you could describe a bit more in detail, what your final goal is. Because "clicking on a polygon shows all points that are within" is a bit vague in my opinion.

Comment: I agree a bit more info is needed. What is the end result? Just those points highlighted on the map? Or selected in the attribute table? Or their attributes shown?

Comment: i edited the question, i hope it is clearer now!

Comment: If you've already figured out how to use the Field Calculator to create a new column in the child layer with the foreign key in it, all you need to do is put that process into a processing model and run the model in batch mode.

Answer (score 3):

Joining - also by geography - is easy with Virtual Layers in QGIS:

[image]

```
select poly.polygontext, pnt.pointtext, poly.geometry 
from mypolygon poly
inner join mypoint pnt on st_within(pnt.geometry, poly.geometry)
```

Result:

[image]

Virtuel Layers is available from within the Data Source Manager